# How can I create a dictionary without distinction and only using python built-in funtions(from two lists)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, zip

I have two lists. Both of sizes are 1013x1. They look like below;

```
l1=["Volkswagen","Toyota","Toyota","Peugeot",..,"Volkswagen","Ford","Toyota","Volvo","Volkswagen"]

l2=[739,403,347,336,310,308,...,302,302,386,370,324]
```

I am trying to create dictionary with them. l1 should be key and l2 should be value. The code is here:

```
d = dict(zip(l1, l2))
```

and d looks like

```
 {'"Audi"': 122, '"BMW"': 141, '"Citroen"': 129, '"Ford"': 203, '"Honda"': 121, '"Hyundai"': 112, '"Kia"': 196, '"Mazda"': 250, '"Mercedes-Benz"': 151, '"Mitsubishi"': 145, '"Nissan"': 131, '"Opel"': 110, '"Peugeot"': 143, '"Skoda"': 510, '"Subaru"': 80, '"Suzuki"': 132, '"Tesla"': 553,'"Toyota"': 102, '"Volkswagen"': 461, '"Volvo"': 416}
```

Why is size of d 20? As I understand it is distinct with **l1**. How can I create a dictionary without distinction only using python built-in funtions?

Comment: Dicts contain each key once. There can be no repetitions. If this is indeed what you're asking, that's impossible.

Comment: Sounds like you want a tuple instead of a list.

Answer (score 2):

Each key can only appear once in a dictionary, but you can have a list as the value:

```
d = dict()
for key, val in zip(l1, l2):
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(val)
    else:
        d[key] = [val]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary is of size 20 because you have duplicate keys in `l1`. Onle the last given `value` of each `key` "lives" the others are overwritten. You can append all `values` to a `key`, if you store a `list of values` instead only the `value` stored by that `key`.

As alternative to a plain dict you can leverage [the `defaultdict` from the `collections` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l1=["Volkswagen","Toyota","Toyota","Peugeot","Volkswagen","Ford","Toyota","Volvo","Volkswagen"]
l2=[739,403,347,336,310,308, 302,302,386]
k = defaultdict(list)

for key,value in zip(l1,l2):
    k[key].append(value)

print(k)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, 
{'Volkswagen': [739, 310, 386], 'Toyota': [403, 347, 302], 
 'Peugeot': [336], 'Ford': [308], 'Volvo': [302]})
```

This is only feasable if you consider imports of basic modules as "python built-in functions".